# can't set select defaut value

Tags: laravel, vue.js

temlate

```
   <bm-offer-confirm  inline-template>
      <select v-model="selectedCard">
           <option v-for="card in cards"
       v-bind:value="card.id">@{{card.info}}</option>
      </select>
   </bm-offer-confirm>
```

in the component

```
module.exports = {

data() {
    return { 
      selectedCard: 0,
      cards: {},
    }
}

created(){
    Bus.$on('setCardsList', function (cards) {
        self.cards = cards;
        this.selectedCard = cards[0].id;
        //alert(this.selectedCard) shows 2 
   });
}
```

if i set selectedCard: 2 in data() it's work correctly and option is selected, but in my example it does not work. selected value is empty(not checked), why? I can select option only  manualuty.

- How you fill the cards object ? Are you getting any exception in console ?

No, it's result of emited in other component

```
created() {
    this.getCards();
},

methods: {
    getCards() {
        this.$http.get('/get-cards/')
            .then(response => {
                this.cards = response.data;
                Bus.$emit('setCardsList', this.cards);
            })
    },


 //The Bus is Vue object;
 //window.Bus = new Vue();
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it to check it holistically.

Comment: How you fill the cards object ? Are you getting any exception in console ?

Comment: Can you show code for the Event Bus? Is `setCardsList` actually triggered in your app?

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

omg, I fixed it

```
created(){

  var self = this; //add self link

  Bus.$on('setCardsList', function (cards) {
    self.cards = cards;
    self.selectedCard = cards[0].id; // before this.selectedCard = cards[0].id;
       //alert(this.selectedCard) shows 2 
   });
}
```